# How to use 〜込みです as a grammar

Tags: grammar, nuances

I am currently studying how to use 〜込み but it's been really hard to find any resources. So far I have made some notes based on my observation of how 〜込み　is usually used, but I am not really sure if I am right. I'm hoping that someone here could have a look at my notes and let me know if I'm on the right track or I've made a mistake. ありがとうございます！

'If we use 込み in a sentence, we are usually asking if the price of using/buying a product/service is included in the price of something else.

e.g. テレビこみですか。Is the price of buying/using the TV included in the fee.

Formation: 予約・料金に＿＿＿＿＿＿こみです・ですか。’

If there's anything that you would like to add please let me know as well, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you have no problem with the meaning but the example is a bit wrong, the money to buy the TV would probably be called テレビの代金 or テレビの購入代金, while the service is 受信料. テレビ込み would be asking if the TV itself is included not it's price. You need to use 代, 料, 費 to talk about the price of something. eg. 宿代, 食費, サービス料. Also, writing 込み as 込 is common on price labels like 税込, 税抜(ぜいぬき).

> その金額は受信料込みですか？
>
> Is the TV service fee included in that price?

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification!